# C program delivers only the UTC time as localtime on Linux using GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, timezone, redhat

I have a C program that runs on two different RHEL6 servers that are configured with the same timezone. The C program uses the time functions from `time.h`. On one of the servers the local time is correctly determined, on the other one the UTC (default) time is displayed independent from the configured timezone.

I've tried to see if the link to `/etc/localtime` is broken but it's a correct softlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/<timezone>` (in this case Europe/Berlin). 
I've inspected the timezone file with `zdump` and the content of the file is correct. The timezone and time of the system is also correctly displayed using `date`. There is no definition of the `$TZ` variable in my bash or anywhere else!

As an additional test I have run the follwing code with and without a `$TZ` variable:

```
    ::time_t aclock;
    ::tm tm_tmp;
    ::tm *newtime;

    setenv("TZ", "Europe/Berlin", 1);
    tzset();
    ::time( &aclock );
    newtime = ::localtime_r( &aclock, &tm_tmp );
    printf("\nDEBUG TIME: %d ", aclock);
    printf("\nDEBUG TIMEZONE: %s \n", newtime->tm_zone);
    printf("DEBUG HOUR: %d \n", newtime->tm_hour);
```

Using the code above and setting TZ parameter differently I get the following outputs on the **faulty** server, assuming that the server time is `Europe/Berlin, CEST` at this moment:

```
without setenv:
DEBUG TIME: 1524241319
DEBUG TIMEZONE: UTC
DEBUG HOUR: 16

setenv("TZ", "Europe/Berlin", 1);
DEBUG TIME: 1524241319
DEBUG TIMEZONE: Europe
DEBUG HOUR: 16

setenv("TZ", "/etc/localtime", 1);
DEBUG TIME: 1524241319
DEBUG TIMEZONE: CEST
DEBUG HOUR: 18
```

So it looks like the "Europe/Berlin" time cannot be found, as the UTC time is displayed and the timezone "Europe" is invalid.

As I said the output / behavior on the other machine is the expected one:

```
without setenv:
DEBUG TIME: 1524241711
DEBUG TIMEZONE: CEST
DEBUG HOUR: 18

setenv("TZ", "Europe/Berlin", 1);
DEBUG TIME: 1524241711
DEBUG TIMEZONE: CEST
DEBUG HOUR: 18

setenv("TZ", "/etc/localtime", 1);
DEBUG TIME: 1524241711
DEBUG TIMEZONE: CEST
DEBUG HOUR: 18
```

P.S. the same **gcc version 4.4.7** is used on both machines.

Is it possible that my timezone database is corrupt on the faulty server? Has someone faced similar problem and solve it?

Comment: Please share the whole program (in the style of a [mcve]) that produces the output, that would at least allow reproducing your issue.

Comment: Under some systems the default local time is taken from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime` (or maybe even somewhere under `/usr/local/`), not `/etc/localtime`. So try checking that file (those files), too.

Comment: In any case, when the zone files (or the default zone file) aren't where you think they are, it can be very confusing and frustrating to debug.  You might try running your program under `strace` to absolutely confirm which file(s) is/are being opened.

Comment: I've figured out using strace that there is some configuration somewhere that links to a false inexistent path /home/mqm/lib/etc/localhost (the right path + incorrect prefix). I will keep you in touch with any outcome or new information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that gcc was compiled with some option that was misstyped, as the C/C++ programms built using gcc have the described time issue and other programs (for example java programs) don't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out, that the problem was the `libc.so` library, which was differently compiled for one of the machines and only used for some C applications excepting linux himself. This explains why `date` delivers the wright output but the C program not.
Using `ldd libc.so` I've found out that the linker was also set to be at the path `/home/mqm/lib` as default, which dosn't fit to my server `/home/mqm/lib/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. To resume, here is the full solution:

**Problem**: Your Linux system is delivering the wright date and time using `date` or some applications but wrong output using C programs.

**Solution**: After ensuring that there is no programming error in your code, check with

`strace -e trace=open,close,read,write,connect,accept yourCProgram`

which path is used to get the time/timezone. You can also check `ldd libc.so` to see where the default path of the linker is. 
If the paths are not corresponding to your linux system configuration, consider recompiling the C library to fit to your system configuration or set `$TZ='fullpathtotimezone'` as a hotfix / workaround.